# sqlite3 & PHP results empty: object(SQLite3Result)#3 (0) { }

Tags: php, sqlite

Im starting to use sqlite3 but I'am unable to get some results.
My database is called database.sqlite3

Inside SQLite command prompt and doing 'SELECT * FROM table'; . works fine. But im having problems with php.

```
$db = new SQLite3('db/database.sqlite3');
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');
var_dump( $result );
```

The result of this code is : object(SQLite3Result)#3 (0) { }

What is worng here?

Thank you.

PD: $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) works but only gives me one record... why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [php doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php), the return value of `query`:

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns an [SQLite3Result object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3result.php), or FALSE on failure.

Have a look at the [`fetcharray` method of the Result object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php) to see how to get (fetch) the the row data.

Comment: Thanks but $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC): only gives me one record. I dont understand why...

Answer (score 0):

So just in case someone is in the same trouble. SQLITE does not work like that. You must walk through a loop to get every row. Then you can create your data array.

Something like this.

```
$db = new SQLite3('db/database.sqlite3');

$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');

while( $row = $result->fetchArray() ){

  echo $row['name'];

}
```